# Spring Kafka @SendTo throws exception : a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to get consumer result, according to [Spring kafka doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#annotation-send-to).

Based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402921/how-sentto-sends-the-message-to-related-topic), it should be possible to do this only by using `@SendTo` annotation beacuse spring boot "also auto configures a kafka template if there is not one already in the context."

But I can't get it works, I still get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:156) 
...
```

This is my listener method

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = "t_invoice")
    @SendTo("t_ledger")
    public List<LedgerEntry> consume(Invoice invoice) throws IOException {
        // do some processing

        var ledgerCredit = new LedgerEntry(invoice.getAmount(), "Credit side", 0, "");
        var ledgerDebit = new LedgerEntry(0, "", invoice.getAmount(), "Debit side");

        return List.of(ledgerCredit, ledgerDebit);
    }
```

What did I miss?

This my the only `@Configuration` file I have on consumer.
Consumer & producer is separated system (e.g. payment system produce invoice to kafka, my program is accounting system that took data and create ledger entry)

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        var properties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "600000");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

`aplication.yml`

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: default-spring-consumer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
```

**Trial-Error 1**

If I disable the `KafkaConfig`, or enable debug during run, this error exists:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class com.accounting.kafkaconsumer.entity.LedgerEntry to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.accounting.kafkaconsumer.entity.LedgerEntry cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.accounting.kafkaconsumer.entity.LedgerEntry is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
...
```

**Trial-Error 2**
If I disable `KafkaConfig` and using this signature (returning String), it works. But this is not expected, since my configuration is on `KafkaConfig`

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = "t_invoice")
    @SendTo("t_ledger")
    public String consume(Invoice invoice) throws IOException {
        // do some processing

        var listLedger = List.of(ledgerCredit, ledgerDebit);
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(listLedger);
    }
```

I think the problem is in here (`KafkaConfig`), since I create new instance of `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`, the `replyTemplate` is null.
How is the correct way to set up my `KafkaConfig`?

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: 2.1.6.RELEASE. Also tried it with 2.1.5.RELEASE, but none works. Updated full stack trace and build.gradle file on question @GaryRussell

Comment: So something else is going on. Run with --debug and examine the auto configuration report. Also try stepping into the container factory bean definition. If you can't figure it out, edit the question to show all your @Configuration classes and properties.

Comment: got some trial-error (I updated the question), but still not get satisfying result

Comment: Well, of course, if you override Boot's auto-configured container factory then it won't be... auto-configured, including applying the template. When you define your own factory, you are responsible for configuring it. It's not clear why you are overriding Boot's `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean since all you are doing is injecting the consumer factory. Just remove that `@Bean` and use Boot's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override Boot's auto-configured container factory then it won't be... auto-configured, including applying the template. When you define your own factory, you are responsible for configuring it. It's not clear why you are overriding Boot's `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean since all you are doing is injecting the consumer factory. Just remove that `@Bean` and use Boot's.

Comment: My fault, get some copy-paste code for overriding `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean. Thank you Gary

Comment: in case i have a producer configuration having a KafkaMessageListenerContainer and a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, both   uses the config of consumer properties  "ConsumerConfig"  factory,  at any request, my ReplyingKafkaTemplate gets kafka reply timeout exception

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers; it's impossible to speculate the problem without seeing your setup. Ask a new question showing code and configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you override Boot's `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` make sure that you set the reply template

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate); // <============
        return factory;
    }
```