# IllegalStateException: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I would like to extend [this](https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test/blob/main/skyshop-gateway/src/main/java/org/engine/config/KafkaConsumerConfig.java) Kafka consumer configuration and add new topics:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    // Authorize

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AuthorizeRequestFactory> authorizeConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "tp-authorize.request");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AuthorizeRequestFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, AuthorizeResponseFactory> authorizeResponseFactoryProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AuthorizeResponseFactorySerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AuthorizeRequestFactory> authorizeKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AuthorizeRequestFactory> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(authorizeConsumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(authorizeResponseFactoryKafkaTemplate());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, AuthorizeResponseFactory> authorizeResponseFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(authorizeResponseFactoryProducerFactory());
    }

    // Capture

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, CaptureRequestFactory> captureConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "tp-capture.request");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CaptureRequestFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, CaptureResponseFactory> captureResponseFactoryProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CaptureResponseFactorySerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CaptureRequestFactory> captureKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CaptureRequestFactory> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(captureConsumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(captureResponseFactoryKafkaTemplate());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, CaptureResponseFactory> captureResponseFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(captureResponseFactoryProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

But when I deploy the code I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.lambda$createMessageListener$1(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:157)
        at org.springframework.kafka.support.JavaUtils.acceptIfNotNull(JavaUtils.java:70)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:156)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:484)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:469)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:356)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:67)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:202)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:174)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:147)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:190)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:184)
        at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:271)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:914)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.engine.SkyshopGatewayApplication.main(SkyshopGatewayApplication.java:11)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045570/spring-kafka-sendto-throws-exception-a-kafkatemplate-is-required-to-support-r

Comment: I already found it but I removed `@Bean` from `authorizeKafkaListenerContainerFactory` but again I get the same error. It's not very clear for me what configuration I need to do.

Comment: Show your `@KafkaListener` - are you sure it is configured to use `authorizeKafkaListenerContainerFactory` in its `containerFactory` property - it sounds not; you should get a different error if there's no bean with that name and the listener is properly configured.

Comment: yes, I managed to solve the problem by adding `@KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale.request", containerFactory = "saleKafkaListenerContainerFactory")`